# Python - Issues in converting time using datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I couldn't find a similar issue anywhere else.
I have a simple dataframe with opening and closing hours per days of the week:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['7am', '11pm'], ['6:30am', '8pm'], ['8am', '10pm']], columns=['open_monday0', 'open_monday1'])
```

When trying to convert any of the column using:

```
df['open_monday0'] = pd.to_datetime(df['open_monday0'])
```

I get the following

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 07:00:00
```

My goal is to convert each column to the proper opening hour (07:00) and then calculate the opening hours for each day.

Comment: setting a `format` should get you going, e.g. like `pd.to_datetime(["7pm"], format='%I%p')`. see also https://strftime.org/.

Comment: @MrFuppes Worked! Thanks a lot, was using the wrong format.